# ionic 2 iOS, can't serve, stuck on copy finished

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, serve

I tried to reinstall my ionic and not work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue yesterday, and in my case it was because of me defining two classes in the same file, I guess it is a bug. However, to discover more about what happening in your case try to run:

**npm run ionic:serve --debug**

it will catch and display any error preventing the build process from complete.